# C#: How to query a SQL Server in isolation?

Tags: sql-server

I need to make multiple queries into different tables in a SQL Server:

1. Query 1 returns data from table 1.
2. Query 2 returns data from table 2.

After query 1 returns, before query 2 is run, table 1 and 2 are both changed by **another session**. Query 2 returns changed data in table 2. This is a problem.

How do I prevent it? Is there a **per-connection/session** setting to make sure that all data queried in this session are from the same logical snapshot?

Comment: Why not just query both tables inside the same transaction? Trying to read data while ignoring changes for the duration of a session sounds like asking for trouble.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Or just use a SP with 2 selects and a transaction.

Comment: On first tab, I started a transaction, and ran the first query on table 1. Then I changed data in both tables on another tab. Then I came back to the first tab and run the second query. The second query returned the change data. Why?

Comment: Well of course it does... thats how a RDBMS works. If you want consistent data at a point in time you need to query it all at that point in time. Or you need to implement some form of time stamping the records so you know which ones to pull. Maybe if you explain why you are doing it that way, and why you expect the data to be unchanged it might make it clearer to people what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My motive is simple. For example the "Employee" table has a foreign key (DepartmentID) to the "Department" table. I first run "select * from Department", which returns only one record with DepartmentID being "1". Then someone else added a new department with DepartmentID being "2" and a new employee that belongs to this new department. Then I run my second query "select * from Employee". I will get the new employee with the new department ID being 2, but my first query didn't have a record with DepartmentID being 2. The resultset breaks referential integrity.

Comment: This is a situation difficult to avoid, specially if you are loading `lookups` and the main data, let's say a list, as indepent calls to an API. The only way I can think of avoiding it is loading all the data in a single transaction which, again, is difficult to say the least in modern applications accessing APIs.

Comment: Even rowversion can't solve this problem. Suppose the rowversion on a Department record is 100, and the rowversion on an Employee record is 101. So I say "select * from Department where rowversion <= 101". Then someone updated the Employee record, causing its rowversion to become 102. When I say "select * from Employee where rowversion <= 101", it will not return the Employee record. But what I want is to return that Employee record before the update.

Comment: @DaleK You said "If you want consistent data at a point in time you need to query it all at that point in time." How to do query it all at that point in time?

Comment: It totally depends what technology you are using to query the data, but most technologies allow you to obtain multiple recordsets in one command.

Comment: @DaleK I can create a stored proc, then call that stored proc from C#. So how to do it in a stored proc?

Comment: As I said above - use a SP with 2 selects and a transaction?

Comment: In which way are transactions not working here? SQL Server offers Snapshot Isolation which is likely suitable here.. also see RCSI.

Comment: (1) On tab 1, I started transaction, and ran the first query on table 1.   (2) I changed data in both tables on tab 2.   (3) I came back to the first tab and run the second query. The second query returned the changed data. So the transaction on tab 1 didn't isolate.

Comment: What transaction _isolation level_ is used? Also, transactions are _per connection_ (Q1 and Q2 must be same connection). At times it may be okay to keep a connection forcibly open (requires code restructuring). For the above test, I would recommend using WAITFOR inside the tx.

Comment: To implement it on transactions, your session would have to open a transaction when user opens a tab and keep the transaction open until user closes the tab. Such approach would be against best practices.

Comment: @user2864740  It is read committed

Comment: @DaleK It doesn't work: <br>
CREATE PROCEDURE ReadTwoTables
AS
BEGIN
    begin transaction;
 select * from Department;
 print '-- first query done.';
 waitfor delay '00:00:30';
 select * from Employee;
 commit;
END
GO

Comment: @SillyDude what do you mean "it doesn't work" and why do you have a `waitfor` in your SP? Thats going to wait 30s then return you all the results? Probably not what you intended. You need to explain more about what you are trying to do, because its really not clear from what you've said so far. [edit] all clarifications into your question.

Comment: As has been said since the start, if you want unchanged data, you have to get it all at the same time *before* you head off to other tabs. Its very unclear why you want to wait until you come back to then try and obtain *old* data - seems you might be going about solving your problem the wrong way.

Comment: @DaleK During the wait for 30 seconds, I updated the two tables in another session. The second query after the "wait" returned the updated data. This leads to the first query and second query having conflicts. That is why I said it doesn't work

Comment: But we still don't understand why you can't just get the data you need, cache it, and not query it again? Why do you need to query twice and get out-of-date results?

Answer (score 0):

To do it you can use system versioned tables.
At the moment when you will open your tab, you will record current SQL Server time for a specific tab. Then you can add to each query on this tab FOR SYSTEM TIME AS OF, like 1st query:

```
SELECT * FROM Department FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2015-09-01 T10:00:00.7230011';
```

and then every detail query will looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF '2015-09-01 T10:00:00.7230011';
```

Versioning tables adds significant overhead, you can read about how to set it up here:[Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15). Also, when you will try to update these records, you will have to add extra checks if other session not updated them already.